# relationship on Jacobi elliptic functions

Tags: special-functions, elliptic-functions

We know that if $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\pi$, then
$\cos{\alpha}^2+\cos{\beta}^2+\cos{\gamma}^2+2\cos{\alpha}\cos{\beta}\cos{\gamma}=1$.

My question is that if $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\pi$, is there any relationship between $cn(\alpha,k)$?

Comment: Your question leaves the impression that, as $k$ is not redefined, something is missing. You should be more explicit.

Comment: When k=0, $cn(\alpha,k)=\cos(\alpha)$, so I just want to know is there any   relationship for general k or with values other than 0.

Comment: thus your sentence should end with "between $cn(\alpha,k), cn(\beta,k), cn(\gamma,k)$"

Comment: Exactly! Could you please give me some hints?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [DLMF section on Jacobi elliptic functions, special relations](http://dlmf.nist.gov/22.8#SS3.p3)?

Comment: Not in general. Recall that $\operatorname{cn}(u,k)=\cos(\operatorname{am}(u,k))$, where $\operatorname{am}$ is the Jacobian amplitude. That does not naturally take angles as arguments, but multiples of the complete elliptic integral $K(k)$ instead and then returns corresponding rational values of $\pi$. I do not believe I've seen explicit evaluations of $K(k)$ that have a factor of $\pi$ in them, so I'm not holding out much hope.